# I need to add a href inside a body for a gmail intent. Works on Android 4.3 but not on 6/7

Tags: android, html, email, android-intent, href

I have the following code:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{user.getEmail()});
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Passenger Excel/CSV");
String body = " <html> <body> <p>" + getString(R.string.reports_send_email_body) + "</p><a href=\"" + key + "\">XLS</a>" + "\n <p>or</p> \n" + "<a href=\"" + key2 + "\">CSV</a></body></html>");
Log.i("","body is: " + Html.fromHtml(body));
Log.i("","body is: " + body);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
getActivity().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Reports link..."));
```

And This is what the body string looks like:

```
 <html> <body> <p>Download your Passenger report here:
 <a href="https://staging.api.psngr.co/api/v2/users/110/trips?start_date=1483228800&end_date=1485907199&format=csv&hmac=1.KqXdqdatvtwLlgXYfDX3fF2vB-k=">CSV</a>
 </body></html>
```

And in Gmail the href do not work, so I cannot press on anything.
What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:
Changed to text/html, like this:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{user.getEmail()});
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Passenger Excel/CSV");
String body = " <html> <body> <p>" + getString(R.string.reports_send_email_body) + "</p><a href=\"" + key + "\">XLS</a>" + "\n <p>or</p> \n" + "<a href=\"" + key2 + "\">CSV</a></body></html>";
Log.i("","body is: " + body);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
getActivity().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Reports link..."));
```

And now  I get this response, still not working:

[image]

PS: I tried on android 4.3 and it works, but starting with Android 5 it doesn't work anymore. any ideeas?

Comment: Note that `plain/text` is not a valid MIME type.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your type from `plain/text` to `text/html`

Edit: also don't use `Html.fromHtml` as that will strip out your `HTML` tags!